# If statement not working in For loop

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

I seem to have issue with this code on netbeans, it seems fine coming from a eclipse

```
 for(int i = 0; i < shards.length();if
            JSONObject obj = shards.getJSONObject(i);
            try{
                page = http.GetPageContentUta(url1,ip);
                http.platform = (String)userClubList.getJSONObject(0).get("platform");
                break;

            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception");
            }

        }
```

Comment: Can you please tell what this code do ?

Comment: This questions usually end up with the same answer. The semicolon is wrong and no `if` is required after the `for`, just brackets. I highly doubt Eclipse not complaning about this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please learn the syntax, [for loop in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). What you have written is wrong. *it seems fine coming from a eclipse* No it doesn't matter, Syntax error is for Java language not for any IDE.

```
for(int i = 0; i < shards.length();if
```

Change it to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < shards.length(); i++) {
     //Remaining if and other codes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a paren when defining your for loop. You also did not state how to increment i.

try

```
for(int i = 0; i < shards.length(); i++ ) {
    //code
}
```